# Rectangle Detection in PCL

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

How do I perform rectangle-fitting in PCL?

PCL allows RANSAC for a limited set of models (sphere, cylinder, etc) but not for rectangles. Is there a way to do rectangle-fitting with PCL's RANSAC or perhaps another PCL module?

Comment: See [here](http://www.pcl-users.org/Defining-new-SACModel-tp2645441p2669168.html) for an answer for a similar question.

Essentially, you have to implement your own SACModel, which is described in the answer.